# CakePHP Containable Help

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i am getting this error when i try the following Statement

**Statement**

```
$status = $this->User->StatusMessage->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'StatusMessageReply' => array(
            'User' => array('condition' => array('User.id' => 1 ))
        )
    )
));
```

> **Error**
>   Model "User" is not associated with model "User"  > [CORE\cake\libs\model\behaviors\containable.php, line 363]

Users hasMany StatusMessage and StatusMessageReply

Comment: Do you really need the Containable? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Does your `StatusMessageReply $belongsTo User` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `condition` instead of `conditions`.